# Redirect from one domain to another, without the user realizing it

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, redirect, mod-alias

I have a bunch of domains on on of my servers. I'd like to be able to redirect some domains to a different domain without the user knowing, so not a 301 redirect.

An example, redirect domain.com to masterdomain.com/sites/domain.com. So when visiting domain.com, the user would be displayed with the data on  masterdomain.com/sites/domain.com.
Also  masterdomain.com and domain.com are on the same server.

How could I do this using Apache? mod_rewritem mod_alias?

Answer (score 1):

If both host names use the same document root, you can do this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} =example.com
RewriteRule !^sites/example\.com(/|$) sites/example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L]
```

This rule will prepend `/sites/example.com` if the requested URI path does not already starts with that.

Comment: Unfortunately, host names are not in the same document root.

Answer (score 0):

GoDaddy calls this a domain Alais.

Here is a link where it is explained

http://webwizardworks.com/web-design/domain-alias.html